How can I provide meaningful commentary about the uncertainty associated with a population estimate drawn form individual ML predictions?
Context: Suppose a team develops a prediction model that predicts the presence of a condition for a given individual. This model is trained and externally validated before being picked up by a prospective user. The user wishes to use the model not just with individuals, but to make an estimate of the prevalence of the condition. They have the input data required for their entire population, though it does change regularly over time.
Question: What additional information can they provide with this prevalence percentage to give an indication of the uncertainty?
Ideas so far:

Bootstrapping samples from the population to get an estimate of uncertainty that relates to variations in the population. Calculate the prevalence in each sample and build a confidence interval. Unsure if this is useful, and if it is, how to decide on a sample size.

Sensitivity analysis where the model's performance is accounted for. That is to say we use the formulae:
$$ x = \frac{PPV}{sensitivity} . a $$
where x is the hypothetical number of observed positives in the new population, and a is the number of predicted positives in the new population.


This is a roundabout way of using the ratio of observed positives to predicted positives seen in the external validation as $$ \frac{PPV}{sensitivity} = \frac{TP+FN}{TP+FP} $$ The same can be done for negative predictions using the NPV and specificity, and then a new prevalence calculated (assuming it wouldn't be more sensible to use the observed population size as the denominator). This allows them to provide some sense of potential error introduced by errors in the model, but unsure whether there are better, or at least, additional complimentary ways to report on how the model error impacts the population estimate.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
